# CSS Conflict Issue with jQuery UI and Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have been toiling over this issue for several days now, and I can't seem to find where the error is.

The site in question is this http://wrhsac.org/

If you look at the calendar here, it is overflowing out of its container, and ignoring styles. Click through to see other instances of the calendar. If you notice in both places it is pulling the same CSS. I tried to edit the CSS, and jQuery and the homepage calendar had no response.

Now navigate to http://wrhsac.org/home Both of these pages pull from the EXACT same .php document, yet they are both rendering differently. On this page the calendar looks appropriate, but the other content does not...

We went a step further and created a test site. The test site loads the calendar properly...

Some things to note:
this was first built on WordPress 3.4.2.
It was then upgraded to 3.9.2 to accommodate Gravity Forms.
This is also a multi-site

I'm stumped, and any help would be great Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't pulling the same CSS.  The broken one is pulling CSS from wrhsac.org/datepicker.css?ver=1.8.4, while the correctly functioning one is only pulling CSS from style.css and jquery-ui.css.

You can hit F12 in most browsers and inspect the elements on your page after it loads.  Then you can see exactly what CSS is impacting the element.

Also, by hitting F12 and expanding the 'head' tag in your HTML, you will see that the stylesheet references on your two pages are very different.  You should either remove the references to wrhsac.org/datepicker.css?ver-1.8.4 - or you should remove the ui-datepicker styles from that file to avoid the conflicts.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that! Get this: It was pulling datepicker.css from the css folder in Gravity Forms, and they were conflicting. We removed it from the folder, and viola! Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem.  CSS conflicts happen pretty commonly since there are so many files.  You can always modify them if you need to (removing it might negatively impact another page) - but remember, F12 is your best friend (it took about 15 seconds to figure this one out after hitting F12)!